# Pattern matching checking for type of tuple

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to use Scala's pattern matching feature to check for the type of the first parameter, and to accept any arbitrary type for the second parameter- though I'm not sure syntactically how this works in Scala as I am fairly new, and I cannot find anything as to how tuples work with one another in Scala as it relates to pattern matching and case statements.

My initial attempt:

```
case foo => (eval(e1, e2), eval(e1, e2)) match
{
    case (S(e1), _) => (bar(e1, e2) + bar(e1, e2))
    case _ => ???
}
```

Wherein, this *should*, in this case, check that the first argument is a string, and accept the second to be whatever, and then do whatever bar wants.

Further, I have seen examples like so:

```
case (_: String, _: Int) => ???
```

however, I am unclear as to how you reference these parameters in your right hand statement.

What is the proper method of referencing these _ parameters in a statement?

Comment: Just in case you aren't aware, `e1` in your `case (S(e1), _)` is not the `e1` in your `eval(e1, e2)`.  For example, `val a = "x"`; `case class S(s: String)`; `S("y") match { case S(a) => S(a) } // res1: S = S(y)`

Comment: @LeoC Right, they should be enclosed in different scopes. That was a poor choice of variable names on my part. Oops! 

I later renamed them lref and rref in my own implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `:` to enfore the type. Below the example. You can refer to any value using a variable and without explicitly declaring type.

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

("Java", 1) match {
  case (str: String, v) => println(s"value: $v")
  case _ => println("something")
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

value: 1
```

Comment: And are you referencing the string with s? Is `s` a keyword in Scala for string, or...is it merely assuming that `s` is the leftover after you locate `v`? Is the $ necessary outside of a string?

Comment: `s` is not reserved in scala

Comment: Then I am a little confused as to what is going on in `s"value: $v"`. What is the `s` doing? It would seem you're not handling the string `"Java"`, but rather dropping the value.

Comment: `s` is used for string interpolation . more info here https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Comment: Excellent- this makes much more sense. Thanks @pamu